# Deploying multiple contracts: contract not deployed to detected network

Tags: web3js, truffle-migration

I'm having a problem deploying multiple contracts. The first address gets written in contract1.json but contract2.json isn't showing an address. My second contract constructor function takes 3 args: bool, uint, address. In web3 I get the following error:

Contract2 has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)

```
var Contract1 = artifacts.require("./Contract1.sol");
var Contract2 = artifacts.require("./Contract2.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
   deployer.deploy(Contract1).then(function(instance){
        deployer.deploy(Contract2, true, 20000, Contract1.address);
     })
    }
```

This is my truffle:

```
Using network 'develop'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0xf04f5da0e200f40dc8b96b505242fda61380088e89f5fd878d6f65534409109b
  Migrations: 0x8cdaf0cd259887258bc13a92c0a6da92698644c0
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0xd7bc86d31bee32fa3988f1c1eabce403a1b5d570340a3a9cdba53a472ee8c956
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Replacing Contract1...
  ... 0x8cf05bf0dbaf4917f4554272b08a36e36c05923ddb1bd96c863b4633d60819cf
  Contract1: 0x345ca3e014aaf5dca488057592ee47305d9b3e10
Saving successful migration to network...
  Deploying Contract2...
  ... 0xf36163615f41ef7ed8f4a8f192149a0bf633fe1a2398ce001bf44c43dc7bdda0
Saving artifacts...
  ... 0x1b968d4d74677f26876edda4aed7026782547dd651b0db5791eb220d4caa030b
Contract2: 0x8f0483125fcb9aaaefa9209d8e9d7b9c8b9fb90f
```

I can interact with the first contract using my dapp. If I want to interact with my second contract I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you want to have

```
deployer.deploy(Contract2, true, 20000, instance.address);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that deployer doesn't handle well Promises/async behavior you have to ensure all contracts are deployed before the deploy script finishes.

```
var Contract1 = artifacts.require("./Contract1.sol");
var Contract2 = artifacts.require("./Contract2.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.deploy(Contract1).then(function(instance) {
        // With the return here we 'chain' the promises
        // to ensure Contract2 is deployed
        return deployer.deploy(Contract2, true, 20000, Contract1.address);
    })
}
```

My preference is use async/await ([issue in Github](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/issues/501))

```
module.exports = function(deployer) {
    deployer.then(async () => {
        await deployer.deploy(Contract1);
        await deployer.deploy(Contract2, true, 20000, Contract1.address);
    })
}
```